# Maximum Actions or Conditions in SharePoint Designer Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, boundaries

Is there a recommended or documented maximum of actions and/or conditions that should be used in a single SPD workflow?
I don't think I would be anywhere close, but I just want to make sure that what I'm building won't be too much of a load on the workflow manager since it will be running several workflow instances at once.

I am working with SharePoint Designer 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Workflow) inside [Workflow limits](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Workflow) see **Maximum depth of a workflow sub-step in xaml (workflow complexity)**.

> There is a hard limit of 125 for node depth in xaml. The maximum value
>   of 121 levels accounts for the default activities (stage, sequence,
>   etc.) that SharePoint Designer inserts automatically.

Comment: I understand there is a hard limit, but you can set the limit to any value. Is there any performance issues if you bump it up?

Answer (score 0):

When you think of creating an application, you should focus on business logic rather than boundaries. In the long run, it is usually better to find commercial solution without any restrictions and giving you a great possibilities for the future. Try out some free trial solutions such vendors like WEBCON, Nintex or any others and see which one is best for you.